# Using Spring-Boot-Starter-Web in combination with ObjectDB

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, objectdb

I am implementing a program in Spring-Boot using ObjectDB. To actually use ObjectDB I have followed [this approach](https://www.objectdb.com/forum/2523) which is working perfectly.

However, as soon as I want to use **`spring-boot-starter-web``** then I am getting the following errors:

> dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required. at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.validate

I have been fiddling around with parameter `jdbc-url` in the properties file as mentioned in many posts. Tried to exclude **Hikari** because probably **ObjectDB** uses his own connection pooling mechanism. But without any results.

Any ideas on how to solve this error?

I am using the exact same code as in the link. I have added **Spring-Actuator** in the pom like this:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You may try specifying dummy JDBC details when required (but possibly with a real existing JDBC driver), and see whether it works, and ObjectDB just ignores it.

Comment: If I add H2 as a dependency and add the jdb-url in application.properties like this `app.datasource=jdbc-url: jdbc:h2:mem:dummydb` it works.

But isn't strange to add H2 while not using it?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases, frameworks that use JPA require specifying a JDBC connection details, including a JDBC driver, which is then passed to the JPA implementation and used by it to access the database. ObjectDB is a JPA implementation that does not access an external database, and therefore, does not need or use a JDBC driver.

As discussed in the comments to the question, a simple workaround is to specify a dummy JDBC driver, which will be passed to ObjectDB and then ignored. It does look weird, but this is the way to go until either ObjectDB implement its own JDBC driver, or the relevant frameworks become more flexible regarding their request of a JDBC driver.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this (in the `pom.xml`?):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.objectdb</groupId>
        <artifactId>objectdb</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

And don't forget to add the database connection in `application.properties`:

```
 spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
 spring.datasource.username=mydbuser
 spring.datasource.password=mydbpass
 spring.datasource.url=jdbc:....
```

See https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-and-jpa for more details.

Comment: Yes, those dependencies are in the pom.xml.

When using ObjectDB you apparently do not have to configure those properties in the application.properties. 

But I have tried the suggestion of the previous comment from user ObjectDB and added a dependency to H2 in my pom file and added a dummy url like this:

`app.datasource=jdbc-url: jdbc:h2:mem:dummydb`

This way, it is working, but I find it a little weird to add H2 while not using it!?